# Проблема с кодировкой русского языка при отправке на сервер - PL/SQL (POST)

Tags: oracle, api, servlet, plsql, plsql-developer

Коллеги! На выходе при получении сервером xml посредством процедуры ниже русский шрифт "ЗАПИСЬ ДОБАВЛЕНА ИЗ ПРЕДВАРИТЕЛЬНОГО ПОИСКА"  заменяется на:

"???????????? ?????`???????????? ???? ???????????????????????????????? ????????????"

Кодировка Оракла windows-1251, однако convert(misc, 'UTF8') не помогает.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<record>
  <ROW>
  <LASTNAME>PETROSYAN</LASTNAME>
  <MISC>ЗАПИСЬ ДОБАВЛЕНА ИЗ ПРЕДВАРИТЕЛЬНОГО ПОИСКА</MISC>
 </ROW>
</record>
```

```
procedure afl_to_akr(l_result in CLOB) is
  req   utl_http.req;
  res   utl_http.resp;
  l_out VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_url varchar2(690) := l_url := 'http://10.120.48.3:8180/ab-int/integroServlet';
  l_body CLOB;
begin
   req := utl_http.begin_request(l_url, 'POST', 'HTTP/1.1');
   utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
   l_body := 'xml=' || l_result;      
   utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Length', length(l_body));
   utl_http.write_text(req, l_body);
   res := utl_http.get_response(req);
   begin
      utl_http.read_line(res, l_out);
      utl_http.end_response(res);
   exception
      when utl_http.end_of_body then
         utl_http.end_response(res);
   end;  
end;
```

Comment: Как вы вызываете процедуру? Какая кодировка установлена на клиенте?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в неверном подсчёте длины заголовка. Используйте:

```
utl_http.set_body_charset(http_req, 'UTF-8');
utl_http.set_header(http_req, **'Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked'**);
utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'Content-Type',  'text/json;charset=utf-8');
utl_http.write_text(http_req, v_content);`
```

Comment: Спасибо, проверю - отпишусь!